# To show that an integer $m$ is prime element in $\Bbb Z[i]$ if $m$ is a prime number of the form $4n+3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number of the form $4n+1$. Then show that $p = a^2 + b^2$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ and $p$ is not prime in $\Bbb Z[i]$. Also show that an integer $m$ is prime element in $\Bbb Z[i]$ if $m$ is a prime number of the form $4n+3$.

First part to show $p = a^2 + b^2$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ is the Fermat's Two square Theorem. And $p$ is not prime as $p = (a+ib)(a-ib)$ in $\Bbb Z[i]$.

But I am facing difficulty to do the second part that an integer $m$ is prime element in $\Bbb Z[i]$ if $m$ is a prime number of the form $4n+3$.

Help Needed . Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

For the second part suppose that $m$ is an integer prime of the form $4n+3$, now $m=(a+ib)(c+id)$ and you use directly the norm so that:
$$ m^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$ and here in all cases we will have $m=x^2+y^2$  which is absurd (not true $\mod 4$, in fact $x^2+y^2=0,1,2 \mod 4$ and $m=3 \mod 4$), so every integer prime $m=4n+3$ is a Gaussian prime

---

This is the characterization of Gaussian primes:

> A Gaussian integer $a + bi$ is a Gaussian prime if and only if either:
>
> - one of a, b is zero and the other is a prime number of the form $4n + 3$ (with n a nonnegative integer) or its negative $−(4n + 3)$, or
> - both are nonzero and $a^2 + b^2$ is a prime number (which will not be of the form $4n + 3$).

Comment: Does this answers your question?

Comment: can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for answers, but:

If $m$ is a prime number and $m \equiv 3 \mod 4$, then for the sake of contradiction, assume that $m$ can be factored in the Gaussian Integers. Then:

$$m = (a+bi)(c+di)$$

Where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(c, d) = 1$ (because otherwise we can divide out by the $\gcd$ and $m$ is not prime). The imaginary part of this expression is $bc+ad$, which must be $0$ for $m$ to be real, so

$$bc+ad = 0$$

$$\frac{a}{b} +\frac{c}{d} = 0$$

However, by the assumption that $\gcd(a, b) = \gcd(c, d) = 1$, we get that $a = \pm c, b = \mp d$. This then becomes:

$$m = (a+bi)(\pm a \mp bi)$$

$$m = \pm (a^2+b^2)$$

$$m = a^2+b^2$$

(since $a^2+b^2\geq 0$). However, [Fermat's Two-Square Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) says that, if $m$ is prime, the existence of a solution to $a^2+b^2 = m$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$, or equivalently $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, is equivalent to $m \equiv 1 \mod 4$. However, our $m$ here $\equiv 3\mod 4$, so we have a contradiction, and thus $m$ is a prime in the Gaussian Integers. I hope this provides a little more detail.